# JavaFx Application Scaling on multimonitor setup

Tags: java, javafx, scaling, dpi

I am working on a JavaFX Project and I am wondering how to make it scale in realtime when dragged from one monitor to an other one with a different scaling setting (I have a 4k main monitor and a 1440p as secondary. The 4k monitor is set to 150% scale in windows settings. I don't care about other operating systems at the moment).
It automatically scales my application to 150% size when dragged on the 4k screen, however it looks blurry, because it is still renderered in the same resolution. Is there a way to find out, when the application is dragged on the second screen?
If so, how do I rescale the UI in realtime? Do I have to write a resize function for every single node in my application? What about Images? How should they be stored? I once did some android programming, where you store images in folders (S, M, L, XL, XXL, XXXL, ...). Is that how you do it with javaFX or is it better to save a high resolution version and rescaling it as needed?

Comment: What version of JavaFX? JavaFX should scale automatically. For resources you use the (at)2x, (at)4x syntax

Comment: It does scale automatically but if the main screen is scaled at 100% and the secondary screen is scaled at 150% the application gets blurred, when dragged on the second screen.

Comment: I am using Java version "10.0.1"

Comment: Then file a bug - there should nothing to be done by a developer - you also did not state what OS which is fairly important as well.

Comment: I am using Windows 10. What is this (at)2x and (at)4x syntax you were talking about? Didnt find anything googling it.

Comment: Freaking stackoverflow did not allow me to write @2x